# Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST ERROR in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

After an update from my webserver i can't enter my Administration system of my site.

I did some research on Google and found that the problem is the PHP update my host company did.

After it i receive the message: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in admin_processes.php on line 199

I found out that he function is outdated. But i realy can't find it why this happens.

This is the code line we talk about.

```
    function suspend_user($POST, $suspend) {

if(isset($suspend)) {

$username = $POST['username'];
$status = $POST['level'];
$email = $this->query("SELECT email_address FROM ".DBTBLE." WHERE username = '$username'");

    $this->query("UPDATE ".DBTBLE." SET status = '$status' WHERE username = '$username'");

    if ($status == "live") {
     return  $username."'s User Ststus was changed to Live.";
        Status_Changed($username, $email, 'Approved');

    } else if ($status == "suspended") {
     return  $username."'s User Ststus was changed to Suspended.";
        Status_Changed($username, $email, 'Suspended');
    }
}
}
```

Hope someone does know something about PHP and this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: RT*M's => http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: exactly where is line 199?

Comment: DuH @MarcB, it's right after line 198 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: function suspend_user($POST, $suspend) {